# Why chatango isn't working in my site?

Tags: javascript

I just can't seem to get the Chatango code work in my site.The chatango code is

```
 <script id="cid0020000166511244679" data-cfasync="false" async      
src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 300px;height: 350px;">
{"handle":"mangaallnew","arch":"js","styles":
{"a":"ff9900","b":100,"c":"000000","d":"000000","k":"ff9900","
l":"ff9900","m":"ff9900","p":"10","q":
 "ff9900","r":100,"usricon":0.75,"cnrs":"0.25","fwtickm":1}}</script>
```

My site is https://mangaall.com ,and in the home page in the side bar you will see a blank space where this code is inserted.I have tried disabling plugin one by one but it does seem to work,I am using the Domino Magazine theme.

Comment: Have you opened the browser console to check for errors? If not then I suggest you do that....

Comment: how? I don't get it.

Comment: If you are using google Chrome Press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` & `J`  If you are using a different browser  just search "**The Browser Name** Short cut to open console" I'm sure you will find out how to view/open the console. When using javascript, using the browser console can be your best friend as it will tell you if an error has occurred and which line within the source.... also good for debugging to view values/arguments passed withing functions via `console.log("something here");`